# Is it possible to use Gmail for a custom domain while still using the email of my hosting provider at the same time?

Tags: email, gmail

Is it possible to use Gmail for a custom domain while still using the email of my hosting provider at the same time?

e.g.

I want to use **ceo@brand.com** with gmail.

and use **department@brand.com** with my hosting providers email application.

Comment: In what way do you want to use the email of your hosting provider...just to read/send email, or something else? Is it a web-based email application? Finally...What is special about your hosting provider's email application that creates this constraint?

Comment: In generally, you can typically use whatever email client you want, and as many as you want.  Hosting providers often offer an email app or web interface as a convenience.  The issue is usually one of data maintenance for you if you access your messages with more than one application or more than one device, and you do it with POP3 or your provider moves messages to trash after they're read.  A few providers may give you a hard time about your using what they consider an insecure email application.  If you have a doubt, check with your provider.

Comment: @Twisty hi there. the hosting providers email will be used for day to day transactions of the company. it is a web based email application. the email hosting provider will need the mx record to be pointed to their servers. i only use their hosting for email and the clients website to a different server. the client asked if he can use gmail while the staff use the email of the hosting.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments, you want the domain's MX record pointing to the hosting provider, but one user with an address in that domain prefers to use Gmail instead.

This can be accomplished two ways:

1. If the hosting provider supports it, configure the one email account to forward all messages to the GMail account.
2. Configure the GMail account to retrieve mail for the address in question from the hosting provider's email server.

Both of these approaches will result in all messages sent to `ceo@brand.com` ending up in the GMail account. However, in both cases all *replies* (and more obviously, new messages) will come from the GMail account and this fact will be evident to the recipient.

From a support perspective, having users from a single domain on disparate email solutions is often a headache to manage. It's important that the users understand all caveats and "sign off" on them. Otherwise their unmet expectations may lead to frustration when the weaknesses of such a configuration become an impediment to business operations.